# Sum of two Dense sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\left\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots \right\}$ and $\left\{y_1,y_2,y_3,\ldots \right\}$ be dense sets in a normed space $X$. Is $\left\{x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2, x_3+y_3,\ldots \right\}$ dense in $X$?

Comment: It's not true, for example if $y_i = -x_i$.

Comment: Thanks @John. Is there any certain conditions, so that the statement can be true?

Comment: Actually your construction is not so well defined. $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots\}$ and $\{y_1, \cdots\}$ are not mere sets. They are sequence.

Comment: First, you're taking numerable dense sets. Second, you're *not* summinmg those sets but rather summing indexwise elements.

Comment: Yep, I agree with Timbuc: The story is take their *sum*: $A+B$ Then you always get a dense set: $\{a\}+B\subseteq A+B$

Comment: Thanks. Any way, I want to know whether there is a condition make $\left\{x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2, \ldots \right\}$ dense?

Comment: Your set $\{x_1 + y_1, x_2 + y_2, \cdots \}$ is not well defined: For example, when $X= \mathbb R$ and $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots\}$ is an enumeration of $\mathbb Q$. Then $\mathbb Q = \{-x_1, -x_2, \cdots\}$. In that case ($y_i = -x_i$), 

$$\{x_1 + y_1, x_2 + y_2 , \cdots\} = \{0\}$$

is not dense. But if you take $y_i = x_i$. Then 

$$\{ x_1 + y_1, x_2 + y_2 , \cdots\} = \{ 2x_1 , 2x_2, \cdots\} = \mathbb Q$$

is dense.

Comment: @DanZimm: Because the reals are a topological vector space so that the topology is especially translational invariant. That means every property you claim holds true whenever it does for a translated version.

Comment: If you choose $\{X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots\}$ randomly according to an i.i.d. distribution uniform over $[0,1]$, and independently choose $\{Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, \ldots\}$ uniformly and i.i.d. over $[0,1]$, then (with prob 1) they are both dense in $[0,1]$ and  $\{X_1+Y_1, X_2 + Y_2, X_3 + Y_3, \ldots\}$ is dense in $[0,2]$.